# Printing Column count(*) in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I am fetching data from a database like this.

```
select categories.categorie_name, count(*)
from names
join categories on names.categories_id=categories.categories_id
group by categories.categorie_name
order by 2
```

i got as a result 2 columns

```
 categorie_name  |  count(*)
```

how ever when I try to acces the count(*) column from my view I can not print what is in the column.

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $categorie)
        echo $categorie->categorie_name." ".$categorie->count(*)."<br>";
?>
```

can you please advice how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select categories.categorie_name, count(*) as cnt
from names
join categories on names.categories_id=categories.categories_id
group by categories.categorie_name
order by 2
```

then use cnt like `$categorie->cnt;`

Answer (score 1):

Use braces `{}` for `count(*)` then you can access that from object properly.

```
   <?php 
    foreach ($categories as $categorie){
            echo $categorie->categorie_name." ".$categorie->{'count(*)'}."<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

In other way just add add ref to `count(*)` as 'cat_count'

```
select categories.categorie_name, count(*) as cat_count
from names
join categories on names.categories_id=categories.categories_id
group by categories.categorie_name
order by 2
```

Now access with `$categorie->cat_count`